# CSS Bootstrap Glyphicon alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have been attempting to create a website as the one sketched in the attached image, with the colored triangles being buttons and the rest just dummy icons.

[image]

For that purpose I have been using Bootstrap's glyphicons (v3 - which are represented as an icon-font). The problem is that the icons fall out of alignment when I use the transform: rotate() function.

```css
.trianglewrapper {
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -100px !important;
}
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
}
.down {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.up {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.down,
.up {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 40%;
  transform-origin: 50% 40%;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
  .triangle {
    font-size: 400px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="trianglewrapper">
  <div class="triangle down">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle up">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle down blue">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle up red">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle down">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="triangle up">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I have attempted using transform-origin (as suggested and solved on other stackoverflow questions) as well as many other approaches that involve changing the HTML structure however with no luck. I either dont rotate the triangles, rotate the triangles but loose alignment (some higher some lower) or as in the included code - get rotated triangles however in a single vertical column.

I would like to know how to align the icons so that they are with the same top and bottom. Also I would accept a suggestion for an entirely new approach.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `transform-origin` and move `up` triangles.

```
.up {
  position: relative;
  left: 70px;
  top: 125px;
}
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/BzRGJR)**

Comment: Simple and effective! However I do not understand the mechanisms behind this, and how were those numbers derived? Nonetheless it works!

Comment: I don't really know how to calculate it. If you change the icon you have to change this values.